Russian roulette with re-spin intuition for asymmetric solution
Suppose we have a 2-player Russian Roulette game where the barrel is re-spun after every trigger pull. There is 1 bullet in a 6-chamber revolver. Should you choose to be first or second?
I am confused about a particular line in the answer that I'm looking at. It says this:

"Each run is now independent. Assume that the first player's probability of losing is p, and the second player's probability of losing is $1-p$. In the first run the first player loses with probability $\frac{1}{6}$. If he doesn't lose, he essentially becomes the second player in a game with a new (conditional) probability of losing $1-p$. So $p=\frac{1}{6} + (1-p)*\frac{5}{6}$. This gives us $p = 6/11$"

What I don't understand intuitively here, is why the second player doesn't have a probability of losing of $p$ (instead of $1-p$) as well. If the re-spins cause the runs to be independent, then there should no longer be any dependence between being first and second. After the first player spins, if he survives, the second player becomes the first player.
So intuitively, why is the probability in the re-spinning case not symmetric like the probability in the non-spinning case? What is the advantage of being second, if the result of the first spin does not affect the result of the second spin?

The advantage is that the second may not have to shoot !

Each run is independent in a certain abstract sense.
We can imagine an indefinite sequence of spins of the cylinder,
always with one live bullet and pulling the trigger after each spin.
In this sequence of spins, every spin is indeed independent.
But the actual game ends when the gun goes off.
This is a piece of information we can apply to the hypothetically infinite sequence of spins of the cylinder to determine the probability of who wins the game.
In that question it matters only on what spin the gun first goes off.
All spins after that will not be part of the game.
The number of spins before the first firing has a geometric distribution.
The winner of the game is determined by whether that number is odd or even.
The odd and even outcomes of a geometric distribution are not symmetric and not equally likely.

It may help to consider up to two spins of the cylinder before we consider the game to become a "new" game.
From the point of view of the second player, this makes a game with the following outcomes:

"click BANG" -- lose
"click click" -- play again
"BANG" -- win

The odds of the second player to win the original game are the same as the ratio of probabilities for winning and losing in this two-round mini-game: $6$ to $5$.
